# Any way to call .copy on trait level, or otherwise immutably copy classes w/o boiler palte?

Tags: scala

I have a hierarchy of errors. Because reasons, they need to extend a trait (I have diamond-shape inheritance patterns.)

There are a lot of cases where it would be useful to be able to attach context to an error from some call site above where it was generated, as shown in `foo` and `baz` below.

```
trait MyError{
  def getMessage : String
  val context : String
  override def toString = context + getMessage
  def withContext(newContext : String) : MyError
}
case class IntError(value : Int, context : String = "") extends MyError{
  def getMessage = s"$value is not a good enough int."
  def withContext(newContext : String) = this.copy(context = context+ newContext + "\n")
  
}
case class StringError(value : String, context: String = "") extends MyError{
  def getMessage = s"Error Encountered: $value"
  def withContext(newContext : String) = this.copy(context = context + newContext+ "\n")
}
def bar (i : Int, b : Boolean) : Either[MyError, Int] = {
  if (b) then {
    if (i < 0) then Left(IntError(i)) else Right(i)
  } else Left(StringError("That needed to be True."))
}
def foo() : Either[MyError, Int] = bar(-2, true)
    .left.map(_.withContext("Error calling bar from foo:"))
def baz() : Either[MyError, Int] = bar(3, false)
    .left.map(_.withContext("Error calling bar from baz:"))

println(foo().left.get)
println(baz().left.get)
```

This code gives a "withContext" method, which is specified on the trait but must be implemented one every case class. As desired, this yields:

```
Error calling bar from foo:
-2 is not a good enough int.
Error calling bar from baz:
Error Encountered: That needed to be True.
```

But I don't like having to add the boiler plate definition of `withContext` on to every case class, given that there's a bunch of them.

Is there any way to move this implementation to the trait level?
A few extra constraints/bonus goals:

- I can't use mutability.
- `MyError` needs to remain a trait, because there are diamond-shaped inheritance patterns beneath it. (I can maybe work around this for a good enough solution)
- It would be great if `context` did not need to be defined on every case class
- It would be super great if the return of `withContext` could be the specific implementing case class, not the generic `MyError`. (That part is not strictly necessary.)

Comment: Some ideas here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40995639/scala-how-to-define-an-abstract-copyable-superclass-for-any-case-class. Pretty sure this has already been discussed and answered but can't find it anymore.

Comment: In general abstracting over constructors is impossible.