# Specify in trait that a copy method is required

Tags: scala

In Scala 3, how can I specify in a trait T that implementations need to have a `copy` method, as gets created automatically for every case class?

In particular, if `A extends T`, then for an `a:A` we should have that `a.copy(...)` is of type `A`.

Comment: And what should be the signature of that `copy`? Why you need it?

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez I don't know how to write that signature. Inside the trait, assume that I have an `val x: Int` and that I want to be able to have a method `def x2 = copy(x=2)`.

Comment: The point of Luis is that you cannot write such a signature, you can't know its parameters.

Comment: Related (and maybe duplicate) of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40995639/scala-how-to-define-an-abstract-copyable-superclass-for-any-case-class

Comment: @mitchus Complementing what Gaël said, try to think how you would use such a method. Like, forget about how to define it, rather focus on how to use it. You will see that you either already know the subtype, thus not needing the abstraction at all, or that you would face the same problem.